# assign time quotes to users

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, quota

Server: Windows Server 2008 r2 x64

Clients (+40): Windows xp, Windows 7 (32 and 64 bit)

number of active directory users: +1000

the question is how to assign time quotes to users? **I don't mean the time of day or week when users can log on**; I mean that we assign each user a specific amount of time (for example 2 hours) a day and users can use this 2 hours with breaks(someone use his 1 hour in the morning and the remained 1 hour in the afternoon) and after each day(24hrs) this time quotes reset for all users;

How can I do that?

Comment: nobody to answer?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that is built into Active Directory.  There are third party tools that can do this.  Most seem to be aimed at an end user.

One thing you could do is to use a login and logout script to keep track of how much time they've used and set a scheduled task locally on each machine that checks to see if that time has been depleted and then force logs off the user.  Though I suspect this would be something that savvy users would probably be able to get around.

Comment: please suggest some of the third party tools

Comment: I suggest using your favorite search engine and searching for parental controls. Applications like CyberPatrol can do what you wish, but aren't aimed at Active Directory, but rather the end user at home.  For an installation as large as yours, working on scripting a solutions would probably be a less expensive way to go..  but will require more work on your part.  I am suprised this isn't included in windows, but in seraching for it, I wasn't able to find anything built in that does what you wish.